# Parsing key value pair with Lua

Tags: parsing, lua

I am trying to parse key=value pairs with Lua.  An example string looks like:

```
str="a=b b=c name=george jetson name2=paul davidson company=radioshack"
for name, value in string.gfind(str, "([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)") do
     print(name)
     print(value)
end
```

result:

```
a
b b
c name
george jetson name2
paul davidson company
radioshack
```

Unfortunately its grabbing the next key and adding it to the value which I don't want.  What am I missing?

Comment: `for name, value in str:gmatch"%s*([^=]*)=([^=]*)%f[%s%z]" do`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to treat spaces in values and spaces before keys differently.
The code below is one way of doing it.

```
str="a=b b=c name=george jetson name2=paul davidson company=radioshack"    
str=" "..str.."\n"
str=str:gsub("%s(%S-)=","\n%1=")
for name, value in string.gmatch(str, "(%S-)=(.-)\n") do
     print(name,"'"..value.."'")
end
```